# Detect when Android app is going to background

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

In my application I need to detect whether my application is going to background or is switching to another activity of the same application... I know that I have to use the onPause method... but how can I distinguish the two cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private static boolean isApplicationGoingToBackground(final Context context) {

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

UPDATE: getRunningTasks has been declared to not be guaranteed to be accurate.

Call in onStop. onStop gets called after onStart of whatever takes over the screen - if its an activity in the same apk package then you're not going into the background. This does require the GET_TASKS permission.

Or bind to a service onStart & unbind onStop - the service will then be onDestroyed when all your activities are stopped (or track binds vs unbinds if you don't want to rely on onDestroyed getting called - because it might not..).

Comment: Finally I added a global variable that is set to 'true' when the Intent is launched and to 'false' when the new view is shown. In this way, when 'onPause' is called and the global variable is not true it simply means that the view is going to background because of Android's will :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct approach to get the app status while background or foreground, but even i have faced this issue, and found the solution with onWindowFocusChanged and onStop. For more details: http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html