# How to call a method when an Android app is closed or loses focus?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, security, ondestroy

Because an app I'm building will handle rather sensitive data I want to sync the SQLite db with the server every time the user logs in, and remove emty the db every time the app loses focus (because the user moves to the home screen or another app).

Seeing [the Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), my idea was to do this by emptying the database in the onDestroy of every Activity. To test the described lifecycle I just Override all lifecycle methods (onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop, and onDestroy), included some log messages in them, and fired up my app.

The log messages are included in my SettingsActivity. When I enter my app and move to the Settings it runs onCreate, onStart and onResume (as expected). When I then click a setting and move to the next screen it runs onPause and onStop (still as expected). To move back to the settings screen I click the back button and it runs onStart and onResume again (still as expected), when I now click the back button again to move back to the initial screen, it (to my surprise) runs onPause, onStop AND onDestroy.

So my questions;

1. Why does it destroy the Activity when the app is not finished?
2. **And more importantly: how can I run my CleanUp method when the app closes or loses focus?**

Comment: What will you do if the user pulls out the battery or the application crashes?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp - We considered those situations as well. The obvious answer is of course not storing anything but keeping everything in memory. One idea we came up with was using an in-memory SQLite db, but for now the orm we use (ActiveAndroid) does not support in-memory databases, it would be a very big hassle (but one we might consider in the future) to either port the orm to in-memory SQLite databases or to go back to our own database connections. Another idea was to keep all data in Java Lists. This would however, making intelligent queries impossible. Do you have another idea?

Comment: encryption of the DB came to my mind, but it must be supported by the DBMS. Also non-DBMS solution might be an option but it depends on how your tightly DB is linked to your architecture.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp - But if I encrypt the database, how can I still search it? Plus, if I encrypt the database, I guess I need to save the key on the device as well. This would basically make the encryption useless right? Or would encryption still be an option?

Comment: this depends on your application architecture. There can be no universal solutions here, and especially not in the comment format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have some more information here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

Even if I think you already read it because you already study the activity lifecycle, you can see in the first figure that the `onDestroy()` is called after the `onStop()` and this call is totally managed by the system : you shouldn't expect any behavior. The system will decide itself WHEN to call this method, and sometimes, this method will never be called (see here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). When system needs memory, your activity will pass in `onStop()` and nothing more.

So, to answer your second question, you shloud read the note in the documentation about the `onDestroy()` method :

> Note: **do not count on this method being called as a place for saving
>   data!** For example, if an activity is editing data in a content
>   provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. **This method is usually
>   implemented to free resources like threads** that are associated with an
>   activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things
>   around while the rest of its application is still running. There are
>   situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting
>   process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it
>   should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

So it's pretty clear that it's a bad place to make your clean-up process. So you shloud use one of `onPause()` or `onStop()` method.

`onStop()` is described like this in the documentation :

> Called when you are no longer visible to the user. You will next receive either `onRestart()`, `onDestroy()`, or nothing, depending on later user activity.

`onPause()` is described like this in the documentation :

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going
>   into the background, but has not (yet) been killed. 
>   [...] 
>   When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be
>   invoked on A. **B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so be
>   sure to not do anything lengthy here.**
>   [...]
>   **In situations where the system needs more memory it may kill paused processes to reclaim resources.**

We now know that `onPause()` is designed to allow you to save your data, and also that after `onPause()` was executed, the system *could* kill your process. So, making the clean-up in `onPause()` seems to be the safest place as you're pretty sure it will be called everytime.

Also, as you can read, making your clean up here can make your app slow, but anyway cleaning and recreating your database at each gain/loose of focus is a really heavy process...

To resume : make your clean up process in the `onPause()` method and your init process in the `onResume()`. **Keep it mind that your application can be really slow with this kind of process.**

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. I still wonder though; how do I check in onPause whether the user is either switching to a different view or the app is actually closing (by the user pushing the home button or by the system requiring recourses)? A code snippet would be very appreciated.. :)

Comment: Here, you are not in the application level but at the Activity level. You are not managing the whole Application lifecycle, but only the "views". So maybe you will never be able to know what will happend next. But, with a custom implementation of the `View.onKeyDown()` method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown(int, android.view.KeyEvent)), I am sure you will be able to make what you want :)

Comment: If the answer helped you, please remember to accept it for other readers coming from Google :)

Comment: "onStop() is described like this in the documentation", this seems to be an outdated quote? This is nowhere described anymore

Answer (score 2):

Destroying the Activity on back is the normal behavior.  From the [Android developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

> There are a few scenarios in which your activity is destroyed due to normal app behavior, such as when the user presses the Back button...

Has for detecting when the application goes to background, there is no simple method call that will let you know that.  However this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358155/detect-when-android-app-go-backrgound) contains some nice answers on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this (call a function) in java part of app.
Only in the native part.

Comment: How do you meann? I can simply write a simple class, import that, and run a method in it in any part of the app right?

Answer (score 0):

About your second question, this way you could run your CleanUp method when the app closes fully. You will need to implement your method inside a service that in this case I named "ExitService"

First create this service class:

```
 public class ExitService extends Service {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        System.out.println("onTaskRemoved called");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        //do something you want before app closes.

ADD YOUR METHOD HERE, or CALL IT

        //stop service
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Then, declare this way your service in the manifest "application" label:

```
<service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".ExitService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Now, just start the service wherever you want to do something before your app closing.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExitService.class);
        startService(intent);
```

Comment: This service "onTaskRemoved()" method calls when the android system forcefully stops the app when it ran into low memory?